# Angular server-side rendering (SSR) | How to get domain name from server

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

My web application is accessible through multiple domains (example.com example.org example.net).

Question: How can I access the domain of the current route?

Please note: I use SSR (server side rendering), answer can therefore not include window or any other browser object. The request.origin returns the server's path, not the client's.

If application is accessed via example.org and current route is [www.example.org/frontpage](http://www.example.org/frontpage)

I need to know the client domain from the backend

Comment: the backend knows it's own domain.  The client sends an origin in the request... that is set by the user-agent.  You'd also have referrer for a GET.  Can you describe what you are trying to accomplish? (in a broader sense...)